# Widen data by group with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have data on Jenkins Job Pipeline Executions and I am trying to determine the average duration it takes to go from Development to Production based upon the start and end times in the data. The data is somewhat like a transactional database where an execution for a Dev pipeline is a unique record, and then the execution of that same pipeline to production is another unique record (only sharing a grouping variable which is the team that ran the job).

Here is an example of the data I started with:

```
  job_id   startTime            endTime               env_type  Team_ID
1  100      8/4/2017 17:14:00   8/4/2017 17:16:00      DEV       A
2  101      8/4/2017 17:20:00   8/4/2017 17:21:00      DEV       A
3  102      8/4/2017 17:24:00   8/4/2017 17:27:00      DEV       B
4  103      8/4/2017 17:38:00   8/4/2017 17:40:00      DEV       B
5  104      8/4/2017 17:40:00   8/4/2017 17:42:00      DEV       C
6  105      8/4/2017 17:51:00   8/4/2017 17:54:00      DEV       C
```

In my first attempt to begin widening the data, I used mutate to create new columns and copy the start and end times based upon the env_type:

```
df %>%
    mutate(prod_job_id = ifelse(env_type == "PROD", job_id, ""), 
           prod_start_time = ifelse(env_type == "PROD", startTime, ""), 
           prod_end_time = ifelse(env_type == "PROD", endTime, ""),  
           dev_job_id = ifelse(env_type == "DEV", job_id, ""), 
           dev_start_time = ifelse(env_type == "DEV", startTime, ""), 
           dev_end_time = ifelse(env_type == "DEV", endTime, ""))
```

Which got me to something like this (also converted time using as.POSIXct):

```
Team_ID env_type      dev_start_time        dev_end_time     prod_start_time       prod_end_time
1        A      DEV 2018-08-01 12:00:00 2018-08-01 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
2        A      DEV 2018-08-02 12:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
3        A     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 14:00:00 2018-08-02 15:00:00
4        A     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 16:00:00 2018-08-02 17:00:00
5        B      DEV 2018-08-01 12:00:00 2018-08-01 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
6        B      DEV 2018-08-02 12:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
7        B     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 16:00:00 2018-08-02 17:00:00
8        C      DEV 2018-08-05 12:00:00 2018-08-05 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
9        C      DEV 2018-08-06 12:00:00 2018-08-06 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
10       C     TEST 2018-08-06 14:00:00 2018-08-06 15:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
```

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(Team_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
), class = "factor"), pipeline_id = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 4000L, 4000L, 5000L, 
5000L), env_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DEV", "PROD", "TEST"), class = "factor"), 
    dev_start_time = structure(c(1533142800, 1533229200, NA, 
    NA, 1533142800, 1533229200, NA, 1533488400, 1533574800, 1533582000, 
    1533142800, 1533229200, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = ""), dev_end_time = structure(c(1533146400, 1533232800, 
    NA, NA, 1533146400, 1533232800, NA, 1533492000, 1533578400, 
    1533585600, 1533146400, 1533232800, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), prod_start_time = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 1533236400, 1533243600, NA, NA, 1533243600, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1533236400, 1533243600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = ""), prod_end_time = structure(c(NA, NA, 1533240000, 
    1533247200, NA, NA, 1533247200, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1533240000, 
    1533247200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

The tricky part is, pipelines may go to dev multiple times before going to prod and potentially even to go prod again afterwards without going back to dev as you can see in the dataframe above.

I am trying to figure out how to create a loop (or a chain of dplyr/purrr commands or some *ply functions) to get the data aligned so I can use diffTime to get the deployment duration. The end goal is to get diffTimes for all pipelines that went from dev to prod, and then to average this number.
In order to accomplish my goal I am approaching this problem by trying to get the data into something like this (after manipulation, the env_type will no longer be valid - but that's ok since I am only interested in the diffTime in the end):

```
Team_ID env_type      dev_start_time        dev_end_time     prod_start_time       prod_end_time diffTime
1       A     PROD 2018-08-01 12:00:00 2018-08-01 13:00:00 2018-08-02 14:00:00 2018-08-02 15:00:00  2678400
2       B     PROD 2018-08-02 12:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00 2018-08-02 16:00:00 2018-08-02 17:00:00    18000
```

In English, what I think I need is this:

For each row where env_type == "PROD", find the closest timestamp for Dev, and overwrite the Dev column with that value -- something like max(dev_end_time where dev_end_time is not greater than the prod_start_time AND dev_end_time is greater than the previous value for prod_end_time). I know the data needs to be grouped by Team_ID and arranged sequentially. I also know that I must start by looking at prod pipelines and then working backwards.

I have started with this:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(Team_ID) %>% 
    arrange(Team_ID, startTime)
```

So that the data is grouped and arranged chronologically. But where should I go from here? I first thought mutate might work:
`mutate(dev_start_time = ifelse((dev_end_time < prod_start_time) & (dev_end_time > prod_start_time -1)), dev_start_time, "")` but I don't know how to get R to look at the correct rows (prod_start_time -1 should be the previous row of prod not the time -1).

I know there has to be some way to do this but I am just not familiar with the function(s) to get it done.

**EDIT:**

For @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero
I am trying to get the point across that grouping by pipeline_id and then filtering the data that has at least 1 dev and 1 prod row will remove valuable data. To demonstrate this point let's look at the data below :

```
Team_ID pipeline_id env_type      dev_start_time        dev_end_time     prod_start_time       prod_end_time
1        A        1000      DEV 2018-08-01 12:00:00 2018-08-01 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
2        A        1000      DEV 2018-08-02 12:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
3        A        1000     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 14:00:00 2018-08-02 15:00:00
4        A        1000     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 16:00:00 2018-08-02 17:00:00
5        B        2000      DEV 2018-08-01 12:00:00 2018-08-01 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
6        B        2000      DEV 2018-08-02 12:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
7        B        2000     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 16:00:00 2018-08-02 17:00:00
8        C        3000      DEV 2018-08-05 12:00:00 2018-08-05 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
9        C        3000      DEV 2018-08-06 12:00:00 2018-08-06 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
10       C        3000     TEST 2018-08-06 14:00:00 2018-08-06 15:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
11       D        4000      DEV 2018-08-01 12:00:00 2018-08-01 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
12       D        4000      DEV 2018-08-02 12:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00                <NA>                <NA>
13       D        5000     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 14:00:00 2018-08-02 15:00:00
14       D        5000     PROD                <NA>                <NA> 2018-08-02 16:00:00 2018-08-02 17:00:00
```

Note how Team D has created a unique Dev pipeline and a unique Prod pipeline. I still need a way to link them and measure the time difference because I know that deployment was used for the same application, but it cannot be done the way you suggest by grouping on pipeline_id.

On another note I know we need a new way to group these teams together to more easily correlate these jobs and there are now plans to make that happen. But I still have to find a way to get this data the best I can with what I have at the moment so all help is appreciated.

Comment: do you care about keeping the DEV iterations separate or could you collapse all DEV time into a single unit for each project?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think we need to keep them separate. The reason being, each time may go from dev to prod multiple times.

Comment: I think you could really benefit from a "pipeline_id" field that uniquely identifies a pipeline. As far as I can tell, you have no way to quickly determine which rows go with what pipeline and that seems like it will be a constant thorn in your side going forward. You're essentially trying to perform a calculation for a piece of data that you're not currently collecting in your data set. That being said, if the ultimate goal is to "determine the average duration it takes to go from Development to Production", then can we just take the average of the development time for the DEV rows?

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero , for simplicity, I trimmed the dataset. There is actually a pipeline_id value within the data (this was originally the variable I grouped on rather than Team_ID). The issue I have with this is, teams are creating pipelines that only go to Dev, or only go to Prod, etc. So for some teams, if I were to group by pipeline_id, there would be only dates and times for Dev for that pipeline_id or only dates and times for prod for that pipeline_id, etc.

Comment: We could easily filter out the pipeline_id's that don't have at least one DEV and at least one PROD row. We could then group rows by their pipeline_id, sum their dev time to get the total dev time for each pipeline_id, and then find the average of those total dev time amounts. This is what you're trying to achieve, yes? If you add a pipeline_id field to the data set in your question then I could quickly get you code to do what I've just said.

Comment: @Nate, I meant to say *each team may go from dev to prod multiple times

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero that would only work for some cases. What I was trying to explain in my previous comment is that grouping by pipeline_id and then removing rows where that pipeline_id does not have both a dev and a prod, would remove lots of desired rows of data. Because unfortunately teams may have a unique pipeline_id for only dev pipelines or only prod pipelines.

Comment: I'm confused, because you had said "the end goal is to get diffTimes for all pipelines that went from dev to prod", but now you're telling me that pipelines that ONLY have a PROD or ONLY have a DEV are also valuable. That seems contradictory. If you only care about pipelines that went from dev to prod, then why do you care about pipelines that didn't go from dev to prod? Are you saying that pipelines with just a PROD should be considered to have a DEV time of 0 (even if there's no row for DEV time recorded)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the code below? I tinkered with one of your dummy data sets so that I could test some different scenarios.

`df` dataframe is the dummy data set unaltered.

`df_w_implied_proj_id` will show you the guts of how I'm determining "proj_id", which is a field I created. proj_id is meant to represent a "true" pipeline.

`mean_dev_df` has the calculation for the mean total diffTime among proj_id's.

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(startTime = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-01 12:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 10:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 14:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 16:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-01 12:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 12:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 16:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-05 12:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-06 12:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-06 14:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-06 16:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-06 18:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-01 12:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 12:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 14:00:00",
                                         "2018-08-02 16:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                endTime = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-01 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 15:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 18:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-01 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 18:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-05 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-06 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-06 15:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-06 17:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-06 19:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-01 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 13:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 15:00:00",
                                       "2018-08-02 21:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                env_type = c("DEV","DEV","PROD","PROD","DEV","DEV","PROD","DEV","DEV","PROD","DEV","PROD","DEV","DEV","PROD","PROD"),
                Team_ID = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"))

df_w_implied_proj_id = df %>%
  arrange(Team_ID, startTime) %>%
  mutate(diffTimeSecs = difftime(endTime,startTime,units="secs"),
         proj_id = cumsum(env_type != lag(env_type, default = first(env_type))) %/% 2 + 1) %>%
  group_by(proj_id) %>%
  mutate(total_proj_diffTimeSecs = sum(diffTimeSecs))

mean_dev_df = df_w_implied_proj_id %>%
  group_by(proj_id) %>%
  summarise(temp_totals = sum(diffTimeSecs)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(mean_total_proj_diffTimeSecs = mean(temp_totals))
```

The main worker bee of this code is this line:

```
proj_id = cumsum(env_type != lag(env_type, default = first(env_type))) %/% 2 + 1
```

To understand it, let's look at the `env_type` values in the data set:

```
env_type
DEV
DEV
PROD
PROD
DEV
DEV
PROD
DEV
DEV
PROD
DEV
PROD
DEV
DEV
PROD
PROD
```

The `lag` function simply returns the value of the prior row. So, as a random example, `lag(c("A","B","C"),default="BALLOON")` would return `c("BALLOON","A","B")`

So `env_type != lag(env_type, default = first(env_type))` would return this:

```
env_type != lag(env_type, default = first(env_type))
0 (note: there's no row before the first row, so the lag statement defaults this to the first element of env_type vector, which is "DEV". And "DEV" != "DEV" evaluates to FALSE aka 0)
0 (note: "DEV" != "DEV" evaluates to FALSE aka 0)
1 (note: "PROD" != "DEV" evaluates to TRUE aka 1)
0 (note: "PROD != "PROD" evaluates to FALSE aka 0. By now you hopefully get the gist of what's going on.)
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
0
```

And then `cumsum(...)` of that vector of 0s and 1s comes out to be:

```
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 9
```

Every increment of 1 indicates a switch from "DEV" to "PROD" or vice versa.

Then we can squish together each even number with it's odd successor by integer dividing every number by 2 and then adding by 1 to get:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

And those are our final proj_id's.

Comment: Made an edit to my post in an attempt to clarify things. No this does not accomplish what I am looking for.

Comment: The first sample of data I provided was really just to show it unadulterated in case someone had a better method of widening the data. I just made them all dev pipelines.

Comment: Oh... I see the issue now. Essentially there's no field to reliably indicate a pipeline, because certain pipelines are given multiple pipeline_id's. I believe this means that we must make assumptions about the data to continue. We need some method to be able to group rows into actual "pipelines", but I suspect there's no way of making a 100% accurate method with the data available. Can I assume both of the following? (1) Every DEV period is followed by a PROD period (2) Every DEV and PROD period with start and end times exactly 1 hour apart on the same day with same team_id are linked?

Comment: Because if we can't assume those things are true, then we run into problems. For example, if it's possible that Team A had DEV and PROD periods yesterday and then Team A also had DEV and PROD periods today, then we have no way of knowing whether or not they worked on the same pipeline both days or different pipelines both days. We have to make an assumption.

Comment: Yes we definitely have to make some assumptions with this data. But the main assumption we need to make is, for every prod pipeline, the dev pipeline that immediately precedes it (chronologically) is the one we want to diffTime on. We have to work backwards from prod to dev for this to work. And unfortunately no, dev is not always followed by a prod, there may be lots of dev executions before a prod execution. In addition, I don't think there are actually going to be any start and end times exactly 1 hour apart - the timestamps I included were just an example - not the actual data.

Comment: As I mention in the post, the logical way to get these pipelines aligned is this: For each row where env_type == "PROD", find the immediately preceding Dev, and overwrite the Dev column with that value -- something like max(dev_end_time where dev_end_time is not greater than the prod_start_time AND dev_end_time is greater than the previous value for prod_end_time).

Comment: Understood. I'm at home now, but I'm planning to work on this tomorrow morning. In the meantime I can tell you that the dplyr function we'll want to use is `lag()`, so if you're still trying to work this out on your own then that's a good starting point.

Comment: I was actually looking into some of the window functions based on a colleagues recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: See my edited code. I think this is what you're after or at least very close to it.

Comment: It looks promising. I am not familiar with case_when. If you have time, would you mind sort of outlining step by step the logic/functions and the operations they are performing?

Comment: I've revised the code. I realized I didn't need to use `case_when`. The way I have it now is much more elegant. I also added explanation for the `cumsum(...)` piece of logic, which is the powerhouse of the code.

Comment: This is going to sound ridiculous, but I think I actually solved this problem with a very simple mutate expression:
mutate("Dev-Prod" = as.numeric(difftime(prod_end_time, lag(dev_start_time), units = "secs"))). Using lag seems to naturally fix the problem. Going to update with more details in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for the answer really goes to [letepsilonbelessthanzero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357864/letepsilonbelessthanzero) since he provided me some guidance on dplyr::lag(). But I have tested the following solution and it works exactly how I need it to.

```
df %>% 
    group_by(Team_ID) %>% 
    arrange(Team_ID, startTime) %>% 
    mutate("Dev-Prod" = as.numeric(difftime(prod_end_time, lag(dev_start_time), units = "secs"))) %>%
    filter(!is.na(`Dev-Prod`))
```